# Cutting down code: "The method changeVote in the type VoteService is not applicable for the arguments (void)"

Tags: java

I am kind of new to Java and am trying to cut down unneccessary lines of code. I am getting an error, and belive I was able to do this in c# or c++: I wish to bind the following 2 lines of code in one:

```
checkVote.setType(null);                
changeVote(checkVote);
//into
changeVote(checkVote.setType(null));
```

I get the error from the title. I know why it occurs (the setter return type is void, and there is no changeVote(void) method). But I still feel like there are ways of doing what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the method `setType` to return `this` instead of `void`. This would violate the JavaBean convention, but it could be suitable for your use case.

This approach is used in the [builder pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

method changeVote possibly takes only checkVote as parameter and you are trying to pass a paramter which is returnig void. In fact this is not even possible in C++.

So those 2 lines continue to be same.